# Как правильнее получать данные из MySQL?

Tags: запрос, mysql

Нужно вытащить по одному значению из разных таблиц... Это быстрее будет сделать одном сложным запросом или несколькими простыми? К слову, если результат какого-либо запроса не подходит условиям, в последующих нет смысла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если данные логически объединяются, то лучше одним запросом.

Comment: а если никак не объединяются? разные несвязанные таблицы? без разницы тогда?

Comment: можешь пример привести, какие данные тебе надо из разных таблиц вытащить?

Comment: 1 ID пользователя и хеш из таблицы авторизации,   
2 количество рубрик с определённым именем и номером группы из таблицы рубрик,  
3 создателя группы пользователей из таблицы группы,  
4 максимальный номер рубрики среди рубрик с определённым номером группы из таблицы рубрик

Comment: эти лучше в разных запросах вытаскивать ) 

К примеру, если надо вывести рубрики - ты вытаскиваешь сразу рубрику + пользователя создателя.

> максимальный номер рубрики среди рубрик с определённым номером группы из таблицы рубрик

а это зачем?

Comment: рубрики по порядку идут. в разных группах разные. чтобы добавить новую, надо новый номер дать. на один больше самого большого для этой группы.

Comment: хм, в запросе добавления вроде как-то можно было вставить из базы